# Layers not displayed in QGIS print composer legend

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer

When creating a print composer legend some of my layers (all point shape files) are not shown in the legend on the map.

[image]

I realized that the symbol markers (3 dots) were different to the ones that were displayed (one dot) but since I am very new to GIS I have no idea what to take from this and it would be great if you could help me out.

(I tried reimporting my shape files, deleted the item, added it again but that had no effect.)